# How can i edit the default drupal node view page

Tags: drupal

I am **trying** to **edit** the default **page view** of a **node** in **Drupal** and i found the file called `node.tpl.php` but **even** if i **change it**, the **node page** on the site **isn't updated**...

So how can i update the node view page so i can added some text, images etc.. ?

I guess that `node_show function () { }` is the one that displays the node but the code there doesn't give me enough detail on where the HTML is created so i can it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the file to your theme's templates folder and clear the cache out before you can use this file. The original file should be at `root/modules/node/`

You can also set a template up for a specific content type by copying the default `node.tpl.php` file and renaming it to `node--CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php`

Comment: As you haven't explained your Drupal version, for Drupal 6, you will need to create 'node-CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php' file (note the single dash)